# drawImage resize image to 500px high

Tags: javascript, html, css, drawimage

I am trying to take the image that is 1280x960 and resize it using drawImage so that is is 600 pixels high.  I have worked out the ratio that I think I need to achieve this but don't know how to apply...

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  canvas.height = this.height;
  canvas.width = this.width;
  
  ratio = canvas.height / canvas.width;
  
  console.log(canvas.width + 'x' + canvas.height + ' | ratio = ' + ratio);
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 300, 500);
}
img.src = 'https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dxo-one-sample-3-1280x960.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

How can I specify the resulting image size, making the width automatic? I eventually want this function to resize any image to 500 pixels high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution, a bit roundabout but seems to work. I created a new image using `toDataURL()` from the original sized canvas. Although the new image is reduced, the total dimension is still that of the original image, such that the remaining space is transparent. Then I set and clip this image into a new canvas. The resulting canvas has the correctly sized image which can be copied and pasted with the desired dimension.

If the snippet below does not display the image in the new canvas, please try the following fiddle which seems to work well: https://jsfiddle.net/jfeferman/u80fhy0z/

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
img.onload = function () {
  canvas.height = this.height;
  canvas.width = this.width;
  
  ratio = canvas.height / canvas.width;
  
  console.log(canvas.width + 'x' + canvas.height + ' | ratio = ' + ratio);
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500 / ratio, 500);
  
  var newImage = new Image();
  newImage.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
  newImage.src = canvas.toDataURL();
  
  var newCanvas = document.getElementById("newcanvas");
  newCanvas.height = 500;
  newCanvas.width = 500 / ratio;
  var newCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
  newCtx.drawImage(newImage, 0, 0, 500 / ratio, 500, 0, 0, 500 / ratio, 500);
}
img.src = 'https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dxo-one-sample-3-1280x960.jpg';
```

```css
#mycanvas {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="newcanvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  That looks like it works great.  Just going through it now

Comment: I am struggling to get this to work outside of JSFiddle, what is the crossOrigin statement doing?

Comment: Have modified this slightly to accept a file input from an upload button which is not working, have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329669/drawimage-resize-image-with-aspect-ratio-not-working-from-file-upload-input

Comment: Cross origin attempts to circumvent restrictions where toDataURL() operates on a canvas with an image from another domain. The canvas becomes 'tainted'. I'll take a look at your new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I applied the ratio to your call to drawImage and it seems to work:

```
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 500 / ratio, 500);
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
  canvas.height = this.height;
  canvas.width = this.width;
  
  ratio = canvas.height / canvas.width;
  
  console.log(canvas.width + 'x' + canvas.height + ' | ratio = ' + ratio);
  
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  canvas.style.width = 500 / ratio + "px";
  canvas.style.height = 500 + "px";
}
img.src = 'https://c.slashgear.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/dxo-one-sample-3-1280x960.jpg';
```

```html
<canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: It does, but the resulting image is still 1280x960

Comment: Strange, that's not the result I get from the snippet above. I see the image with adjusted dimension. Using latest chrome browser.

Comment: If I right click and copy the resulting image into photoshop it is still 1280x960 with a black background

Comment: I've adjusted the snippet so that the canvas is sized proportionally to your requirements. The image fits inside the canvas correctly but this is a nominal dimension. The original image is still 1280x960. What you need is a different solution using toDataURL() which I can provide in a separate answer.

Comment: That would be great, I have been reading up on toDataURL but can't find a relevant example